# Structured Streaming set checkpointLocation offsets replication factor

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Structured Streaming of Spark 2.2 and running several long-term streaming jobs. Every day or two days, I will meet following errors:

> User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Could not obtain block: BP-xxx:blk_xxx file=/xxx/offsets/xxx

And when I meet this error, the job keeps failing on restarting. I have to manually delete checkpoint files.

I find that the offsets/commits files under the checkpointLocation is of replication factor 1. And I guess changing the replication factor to 3 will 
solve this problem.

**How to set the replication factor of the checkpointed offsets/commits to 3?**

Answer (score 0):

The question seems partial. Spark itself cannot maintain a replicated checkpoints. However if you are saving the checkpoints to HDFS you can configure the hdfs to have replication factor of 3 by changing the following configuration in your `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>
```

***Update 1:***
Screenshot of offset replication:

[image]

Screenshot of commits replication:

[image]

Comment: Please try out the answer youself before posting it out. The problem is unrelated with the hdfs configuration. I read the source code of spark 2.2, it is hard coded to 1.

Comment: @宇宙人 I did try out my answer and it works. As already mentioned the question is partial. As rightly pointed by you the replication factor is hard-coded to 1 and its not by chance. There is a reason for it. Spark documentation clearly points out that it is the responsibility of the user to save checkpoints in a fault tolerat manner which basically means to save to s3 or hdfs like file sysyem.

Comment: Do you try structured streaming?  Do you check the folders under the checkpointLocation? And you will find that offsets/commits with replication factor 1, while metadata/sources/state with replication factor 3. And the hdfs-site.xml does have configured with dfs.replication=3. I don't think there is a way to save it in a fault tolerent way with your suggested method.

Comment: @宇宙人 I have updated my answer with relevant screenshots showing the HDFS replication factor to be 3 for offsets/commits. I'm still worried if I answered your question. And yes I'm using spark structured streaming 2.2.1 and the streams are running perfectly fine in production

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out later in the following days. The infrustucture is a little bit indirect in my environment. I need to meet many people to figure each part out. Thanks again, you let me know it is possible to save it with replication factor 3.

Comment: @宇宙人 Glad I could help.

Comment: I made sure that the hadoop is configured with dfs.replication=3, and the hdfs-site.xml uploaded when submitting the spark app is also configured with dfs.replication=3, and I also programmatically set SparkSession with spark.hadoop.dfs.replication=3, but none of them work. I'm using spark 2.2.0.

Comment: @宇宙人 just to be sure do you have Hadoop configuration location in your spark-env.sh?

Comment: I think it should be. If it is not, I think --conf spark.hadoop.dfs.replication=3 should overwrite the configuration. I feel very strange that all normal hdfs files and some directories under the checkpointLocation is with replication factor 3, only the offsets and commits directories under checkpointLocation is with replication factor 1.